# Perl Use of uninitialized value in regexp compilation at warning

Tags: perl

I have pasted small snippet of code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $start_data;
my $name = "Data_abc";

while(<DATA>){
    my $line = $_;
    if ($line =~ /^Start:\s+/){
        my ($st, $data) = split(/\s+/,$line); 
        $start_data = $data; 
    }

    for( $name ){
        /^$start_data/ and do { next; }
    }

    print "END of execution\n";
}
print $start_data;

__DATA__
===============================
2020-05-20            Name
===============================
Start:              Data_abc
Load:               Load_data
```

Script is working as expected but it throws up warning -

```
Use of uninitialized value $start_data in regexp compilation at storage_problem.pl line 18,
```

Since I have already declared `$start_data` at the beginning, why this warning it shows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$start_data` was declared, but you did not assign it a value before you tried to read it in the regex.  Therefore, it is undefined.

When I run your code, I get 3 warning messages, corresponding to your 1st 3 lines of `DATA`.  Those 3 lines do not match your regex (they don't start with `Start:`).

Since you did not initialize `$start_data` with a value, you get the `uninitialized` warning.

Once the 4th line is read, you stop getting the warnings because `$start_data` is assigned a value (`Data_abc`).

Answer (score 3):

The code provided by OP declares `$start_data` but does not initialize it.

On read of first line this `$start_data` checked in `/^$start_data/` regular expression which is equivalent to `/undef/` what causes following message

> Use of uninitialized value $start_data in regexp compilation at storage_problem.pl line 18,

Perhaps the code should be written us following

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use autodie;

my $start_data;
my $name = "Data_abc";

while(<DATA>){
    next unless /$name/;
    $start_data = $1 if /^Start:\s+(\w+)/;
}

say 'END of execution';
say "Start: $start_data" if defined $start_data;

__DATA__
===============================
2020-05-20            Name
===============================
Start:              Data_abc
Load:               Load_data
```

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no guarantee that that `if` block is going to execute.

You can either ask if the variable is set before to read it, or just initialize to whatever value makes sense for your use case.